# Problem with finding a string in an arrayList with objects

Tags: java

I have two classes called Pokemon.java and Move.java which contain methods for creating and modifying Pokemon and their moves. I've created all of the required methods, but I'm issues with the knowsMove method, specifically the one that requires a `String` instead of a `Move`. The method is supposed to see if a move with the given string is in a list of moves. When I tested out the method, it was returning true when it was supposed to be returning false, since there was no move with the string that I've given it.

Here is the code for the Pokemon.java class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Pokemon
{
    // Copy over your code for the Pokemon class here
    // Private constants
    private static final int MAX_HEALTH = 100;
    private static final int MAX_MOVES = 4;
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private int opponentHealth;
    public static int numMovesForPokemon = Move.getNumOfMoves();
    private int doesListContainName = 0;
    private Move move;
    private ArrayList<Move> moveListForPokemon = new ArrayList<Move>();
    private String pokemonImage;

    // Write your Pokemon class here
    public Pokemon(String theName, int theHealth)
    {
        name = theName;
        if(theHealth <= MAX_HEALTH)
        {
            health = theHealth;
        }
    }

    public Pokemon(String name, String image)
    {
        this.name = name;
        health = 100;
        pokemonImage = image;
    }

    public Pokemon(String theName)
    {
        name = theName;
    }    

    public void setImage(String image)
    {
        pokemonImage = image;
    }

    public String getImage()
    {
        return pokemonImage;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health)
    {
        this.health = health;
    }    

    public boolean hasFainted()
    {
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean canLearnMoreMoves()
    {
        if(numMovesForPokemon < 4)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean learnMove(Move other)
    {
        if(canLearnMoreMoves())
        {
            moveListForPokemon.add(other);
            numMovesForPokemon++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void forgetMove(Move other)
    {
            moveListForPokemon.remove(other);
    }

    public ArrayList<Move> displayList()
    {
        return moveListForPokemon;
    }

    public boolean knowsMove(Move move)
    {
        if(moveListForPokemon.contains(move))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean knowsMove(String moveName)
    {
        for(Move m : moveListForPokemon)
        {
            if(m.getName() != null && m.getName().contains(moveName))
            {
                doesListContainName = 1;
            }

        }

        if(doesListContainName == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean attack(Pokemon opponent, Move move)
    {
        if(knowsMove(move))
        {
            opponentHealth = opponent.getHealth();
            opponentHealth -= move.getDamage();
            opponent.setHealth(opponentHealth);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean attack(Pokemon opponent, String moveName)
    {
        if(knowsMove(moveName))
        {
            opponentHealth = opponent.getHealth();
            opponentHealth -= move.getDamage();
            opponent.setHealth(opponentHealth);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }    

    public String toString()
    {
        return pokemonImage + "\n" + name + " (Health: " + health + " / " + MAX_HEALTH + ")";
    }
    // Add the methods specified in the exercise description
}
```

Here is the code for the Move.java class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Move
{
    // Copy over your code for the Move class here
    private static final int MAX_DAMAGE = 25;
    private String name;
    private int damage;
    public static int numMoves;
    private ArrayList<Move> moveList = new ArrayList<Move>();

    public Move(String theName, int theDamage)
    {
        name = theName;
        if(theDamage <= MAX_DAMAGE)
        {
            damage = theDamage;
        }
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDamage()
    {
        return damage;
    }

    public static int getNumOfMoves()
    {
        return numMoves;
    }

    public ArrayList<Move> getList()
    {
        return moveList;
    }    

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " (" + damage + " damage)";
    }    
    // Add an equals method so we can compare Moves against each other

    public boolean equals(Move other)
    {
        if(name.equals(other.getName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }     
}
```

Finally, here is the code for PokemonTester.java where I test out the methods:

```
public class PokemonTester extends ConsoleProgram
{
    private PokemonImages images = new PokemonImages();
    public void run()
    {
        // Test out your Pokemon class here!
        Pokemon p1 = new Pokemon("Charrizard", 100);
        Pokemon p2 = new Pokemon("Pikachu", 100);
        Move m1 = new Move("Flamethrower", 20);
        Move m2 = new Move("Fire Breath", 15);
        p1.learnMove(m1);
        System.out.println("Pokemon knows move 1: " + p1.knowsMove(m1));
        System.out.println("Pokemon knows move 1 (String): " + p1.knowsMove("Flamethrower"));
        System.out.println("Pokemon knows move 2 (String): " + p1.knowsMove("Fire Breath"));
        System.out.println("Pokemon knows move 2: " + p1.knowsMove(m2));
        System.out.println("Move 1 Damage: " + m1.getDamage());
        System.out.println("Pokemon attack opponent with move 1: " + p1.attack(p2, m1));
        System.out.println("Opponent health: " + p2.getHealth());
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: My question is why doesn't the method get the names for the moves correctly, and why it returns true instead of false?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the question. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: please edit your post to remove unnecessary code. we just want to see a [mre]

Comment: please also see [Asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doesListContainName should not be a class variable and instead be a local variable for the "knowsMove" method. The variable doesListContainName is initialized as 0, then the test called "knowsMove" with a move that it does know, so the doesListContainName variable is set to 1. The test then calls knowsMove with an unknown move but the doesListContainName is still 1 so it returns true as well.

Comment: I see, I simply forgot to change the variable doesListContainName back to 0 after the method returned true, thank you!

Comment: I would suggest making it a local variable to the method so it inits to 0 every time it is called, unless for some reason you need to use it outside of that method?